# MultiSplit Panel disaapears if one of the panels dragged too far

Tags: java, swingx, jxmultisplitpane

I am using the `SwingX MultiSplitPane, JXMultiSplitPane`. The pane has three separate panels: a left panel, a middle panel, and a right panel. If I expand the left panel too much, it causes the right panel to disappear and I can't get it back.

Is there any way to constrain the behavior of the user to prevent them from expanding the width of a panel beyond a certain size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was found by looking at sample code here:
   http://www.massapi.com/source/xui32/src/net/xoetrope/swing/app/XDockingApp.java.html
and here
http://www.java.net/node/705562.

Basically, you need to restrain the size of the divider so that it doesn't disappear.